# Using a gem in a pure ruby script (not Rails)

Tags: ruby, bundler, require

A ruby file:

```
gem "my-gem", git: "https://github.com/gem123.git", branch: "some-branch"
require "my-gem"

var1 = SomeGem::some_method123
puts var1
```

It says `Could not find 'my-gem' (>= 0) among 330 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)`. Why not? I  need a special branch of a gem and don't want to clone the repository.

Comment: You could use the `Gemfile`, just like it is intended to be used. :)

Comment: @Achrome, and how would my script know that there is a Gemfile it has to use?

Comment: `bundle install` should work fine for you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [bundler](http://bundler.io/). Create a `Gemfile` along side your ruby script.

In the `Gemfile`, add:

```
gem "my-gem", git: "https://github.com/gem123.git", branch: "some-branch"
```

Make sure bundler is installed:

```
gem install bundler
```

And install the required gems:

```
bundle install
```

Now just initialize bundler at the top of your script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

# require your gems as usual
require 'my-gem'
```